# Spree Commerce missing translation es-MX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, spree-auth-devise

Hi im new to spree and im building an online ecommerce solution for a client in Mexico, i need all translations working properly, the issue appears when I hit SignOut or Cerrar Sesion, which logs the user out, i get the following: translation missing: es-MX.devise.sessions.spree_user.signed_out, I cannot locate a solution for this, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem when setting up a store in Danish. The keys at this path are missing from the translation files. My quick fix was editing my `config/locales/da.yml` and adding a `devise` section:

```
da:
  devise:
    sessions:
      signed_in: Du er nu logget ind.
      signed_out: Du er nu logget ud.
```

You don't need the sub-key `spree_user` (resource name) since translation finder will automatically move "up" the tree when not found. You can read into `devise_controller` from the `devise` gem if interested.

You can find the Mexican Spanish terms you need from here: https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_i18n/blob/master/config/locales/es-MX.yml#L319

For some reason the files in `spree_i18n` call the node `user_sessions` rather than `sessions`. This seems to be the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks that actually helped me solved the translation problem!! The problem im having now is that for some reason if I switch locale to :en on the web site, and I go to sign out, i get the signout message in spanish instead of english, but this im asking on another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350851/spree-translation-to-es-mx-not-working-properly